# Is it possible to render text as being "cut out" from a layer in in qt5?

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt, pyqt5, alphablending

I'm new to `ui` design and was wondering how I could achieve an effect where some font-based text on top of a layer is drawn as being "cut-out" from said layer, if that's even possible.

[image: concept]

`Basically akin to the example below` Ideally something where the layer the text is *"cut out"* from can itself have effects, such as semi-transparency and/or blur, where the effect would still work if said layer has a translation across the background.

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a `QPainterPath` and a `QPainter`.

Use `QPainterPath` to define the white part on your image. First, create a path with a rect (rounded rect). Then, add your text with the right font to the path. By default, the fill rule will remove the text from the rect.

Use `QPainter` to draw the path on your background image. Don't forget to enable antialiasing for a better render.

An example:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setPixmap(self.makePixmap("knockout"))

    def makePixmap(self, text):
        background = QPixmap(600, 80)
        background.fill(Qt.red)      # Your background image

        textMask = QPainterPath() 
        textMask.addRect(75, 20, 300, 40) # The white part
        textMask.addText(QPoint(90, 50), QFont("Helvetica [Cronyx]", 24), text) # the path will substract the text to the rect

        painter = QPainter(background)
        painter.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.TextAntialiasing)

        painter.fillPath(textMask, QBrush(Qt.white)) # Will draw the white part with the text "cut out"

        painter.end()
        return background
```